# C# Code Design Issue

Tags: c#, design

I am building a small application and I am trying to understand the best way to approach the design. I am looking for some guidance/advice how best to approach the following issue. Please bear with me. Thank you.

What I have is that I receive a set of data, real time. I then analyze the data for patterns. The patterns are classes that derive from an abstract class which implements an interface. The number of patterns will change over time as patterns are added/removed. In addition, depending on the access level of the user, the data is analyzed with different pattern options. For example, if I have five patterns, A, B, C, D and E, level 100 access may only analyze the data with pattern A whereas access level 300 will analyze with patterns B, D and E, and access level 500 will analyze with all the patterns. The access levels are linked to the user, and a user can have different access levels on different data streams.

My thought is to create a hash table or dictionary for the patterns and a db for the users and their various access levels. Is this the best way to go or is there a better approach that will work in real time?

Any suggestions or advice on how best approach this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.